# I accidentally kicked my puppy in the mouth, help me please

Tags: dogs, fear, injury

Disclaimer: I love my animals and this was in no way intentional and I have been shrouded in guilt since this happened.

OK, so earlier today, about an hour ago, I was playing with my 5 month old puppy. His favourite game is chasing his squeaky burger toy after I kick it; however earlier today when I went to go to kick it, he decided to jump towards the toy resulting in me kicking him in the mouth with the ball on the side of your feet (I don't know what it is called). He immediately ran up on top of the sofa and hid in the corner yelping for about 10-15 seconds with his mouth wide open before he stopped, he then rushed over to my mum for cuddles. I straight away ran to him and stroked him to try and say sorry, but couldn't help but think if I damaged one of his teeth or his jaw when I kicked him because of how long he had his mouth open when he was yelping.

He has never yelped that badly before and there is a little cut on my foot which I presume is from his canine tooth. After about 5 minutes he returned to his normal self, trying to lick me and play. I gave him one of his more hard and chewy treats to see if it hurt him to bite and he seemed fine and loved it! But I'm still slightly worried for him.

That's why I was wondering if any of you had been in a similar situation and if so, what you did in that situation.

P.S. I have checked inside of his mouth and there doesn't appear to be any blood or missing teeth.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These things ... happen, especially with puppies and smaller dogs.

The good news is it's probably fine. He's acting normal, and there's no real lasting damage from what you said. He probably was surprised, maybe bit himself and kinda decided he wanted a little attention. He also probably thought you were mad at him too.

We kinda accidentally stepped on or accidentally kicked our dog a few times and he's fine so far. You'll get into the habit of being more cautious as will he as you both get used to each other.

Comment: +1 accidents will happen even if you're being careful. But in my experience, pets seem to "know" that it was just an accident. Usually they are back to normal in a minute or two. My cats will run off a few metres, look at me in anticipation of the "I'm sorry" attention and petting they're about to get, and then rush back to me as soon as I extend my hand. I do say "I'm sorry", and they seem to recognise it as an apology.

Comment: @mhwombat: That's cats for you...