# I accidentally elbowed my dog in the mouth

Tags: dogs, behavior

I was putting my dog's frozen treat in freezer  and my dog was following me. The freezer was the swing door type under the fridge. So I thought the close was closing on me but instead I elbowed my dog in mouth thinking it was the freezer door. I don't know I hit him too hard but he suddenly started acting aloof after and I'm trying to apologize but he won't go near me. I don't think I got wounded in the accident either. What should I do? Help

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/19034/429 related, though it feels like the person who did it got off lightly

Comment: The more *you* act strangely by trying to apologize, the more your dog will act strangely in reaction to your strange behavior. Dogs don't have a concept of apologizing. He probably thinks he was chastised for trying to go into the freezer and is behaving extra-careful now. The sooner you return to normal behavior, the sooner your dog can do the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I regain my dog's trust after accidentally hurting them with a toy?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/16600/how-can-i-regain-my-dogs-trust-after-accidentally-hurting-them-with-a-toy)

Answer (score 1):

Say oops, make a bit of extra effort to show the dog you like it for a day or two, and forget about it. If it doesn't happen again, the dog will forget about it too. Accidents happen.